In Swift, does empty array literal allocate zero capacity for storage?
let arr: [Int] = []

Does Swift not allocate any buffer in this instance because the array literal is empty?

yes, empty array's capacity is always zero with some exceptions

Looking at the source code of the standard library, we can find a class named __EmptyArrayStorage.
/// Class used whose sole instance is used as storage for empty
/// arrays.  The instance is defined in the runtime and statically
/// initialized.  See stdlib/runtime/GlobalObjects.cpp for details.
/// Because it's statically referenced, it requires non-lazy realization
/// by the Objective-C runtime.
///
/// NOTE: older runtimes called this _EmptyArrayStorage. The two must
/// coexist, so it was renamed. The old name must not be used in the new
/// runtime.
@_fixed_layout
@usableFromInline
@_objc_non_lazy_realization
internal final class __EmptyArrayStorage
  : __ContiguousArrayStorageBase {

So there is still a part of the heap allocated for storing this instance of __EmptyArrayStorage, but all the empty Swift arrays will share the same storage.

Also possible that the compiler will completely optimize away the definition, depending on how it is used, right?

@jnpdx yes. From my experience the compiler optimises pretty aggressively with -O.

There's just 1 instance of it, and it's shared among all empty arrays: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/9773e89bb770f75076dc50e9e77457d281534386/stdlib/public/core/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift#L126-L132
